# Drawing a grid on array of images

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, subfloats

I have nice story to tell with pictures. There Maltese type cross which is processing and twisting at the same time. So to make it more visual in paper i need grid something like this [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/15717) but on the whole array of images.

How Can I draw a grid on the array of images. I have something like this, sequence of images in which something is precessing around image's locus, and want to give more visual effect to reader.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\advance\leftskip-3cm
\advance\rightskip-3cm

\begin{tabular}{llll}

\hspace{5mm}\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image1}} &
\hspace{-5mm}\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image2}}\\
\hspace{5mm}\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image3}} &
\hspace{-5mm}\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image4}} \\

\end{tabular}
\caption{Time Evolution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility using TikZ and the code in the answers to [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,align=center] (image) at (0,0) {%
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image1}}\quad
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image2}}\\
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image3}}\quad
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image4}}
};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Time Evolution}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear users, I have nice story to tell with pictures. There Maltese type cross which is preccessing and twisting at the same time. So to make it more visual in paper i need grid something like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz but on the whole array of images- array is typically what i have wrote. Merci

Comment: @Davit please see my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect answer, and nice logical style. My acknowledgments.

Comment: Please see what I have written, in some cases I need individual grid on each of  picture inside my figure-array. Problem is  why I can't use \subfloat before \includegraphics in this case. I want to since I need caption below each image. Also I guess it should be some solution like to define new command to not write this on each element of array.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113463/drawing-a-grid-on-each-image-inside-the-array-of-images

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%\advance\leftskip-3cm
%\advance\rightskip-3cm

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image1}} &
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image2}}\\
\hline
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image3}} &
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image4}} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Time Evolution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I added `demo` as I didn't have the images (you'll need to remove it)

I changed the tabular preamble to 2 column as you only had two columns in the body.

I removed the settings of left and right skip (which should *never* be set directly in LaTeX)

and I added vertical and horizontal rules.

---

With rules *over* the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image1}} &
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image2}}\\
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image3}} &
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 70mm 20mm,clip,scale=0.15]{image4}} \\
\noalign{\null}
\end{tabular}\begin{picture}(0,0)
\color{blue}\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\multiput(0,0)(0,10){10}{\line(-1,0){120}}
\multiput(0,0)(-10,0){13}{\line(0,1){90}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Time Evolution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologize as a very beginner, I did not get. Is the second one  separate document? I tried I get error \end{pspicture} row. And why skip should not be set, if not then how handle the position of figure. And let me express my gratitude for your answer.

Comment: The `pspicture` code was in the other answer by bugbusters not mine, `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` are TeX primitives and if you set them by hand you will completely break latex's list and display environments which need to set several lengths in compatible ways. You just want `\centering` here.

Comment: Sorry,then what about grid, my issue is to draw grid on my whole array.

Comment: @Davit isn't that what my answer does? If not you will need to clarify your question.You have four images and it makes a 2x2 grid with each image centred in one of the squares. Or do you want a grid _over_ your images?

Comment: Monsieur Carlisle, I need grid ON images

Comment: @Davit update with grid over images as promised:-)

Comment: Great!This was my first day here, and I am enjoying.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\def\row{10}
\def\col{10}
\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\col,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\row,
}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=cyan,
    gridlabels=0pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\numexpr\col*2,\numexpr2*\row)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput[bl](\col,0){\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \rput[bl](0,\row){\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
    \rput[bl](\col,\row){\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why I have an error on \end{pspicture} line? Merci

Comment: @Davit use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`