# How can I overlay a grid with LaTeX on an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have an image (782x512pixels):
[image]

I would like to overlay a coordinate system (with a grid) where the bottom left hand corner is (0,0) the bottom right is (782,0) top right (782,512) and the top left hand corner (0, 512).

[image]

Ideally the code should be able to create a grid based on any size image (x,y) I place.

The output should be with an appropriate superimposed grid over the image with vertical and horizontal lines).

I tried looking at [Drawing a grid on array of images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113287/drawing-a-grid-on-array-of-images), but didn't understand how it was done, and I also want it to be for one image and not an array.

Comment: How about [this possibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799)?

Comment: @marmot that's really close to what I want, but how can make it so the x,y axis reflect the number of pixels on the image?

Comment: @marmot I also found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture) but again I want to use the images pixel dimensions... :/

Comment: related : [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/138900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using `overpic` with  the `abs` option, but probably you may want use `percent` and forget about the original or final image size in pixels. Once you find the right coordinates for the overlay, set the `grid` option to `false`.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section*{Grid in percentage}\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[percent,grid=true,tics=20,scale=.5]{example-image-16x10.png}
\put(20,5){\sffamily\bfseries (that is 400 $\times$ 250 pixels)}
\end{overpic}

\section*{Grid with absolute pixels}\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[abs,grid=true,tics=40,scale=.5]{example-image-16x10.png}
\put(39,10){\sffamily\bfseries (now are 200 $\times$ 125 pixels)}
\end{overpic}

\newpage
\section*{Original image}\bigskip

\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-16x10.png}

($300\times200\,\mathrm{bp} = 400 \times 250\,\mathrm{pixels}$)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not claim that I invented this. Rather, I believe I saw something very similar before, but I really cannot find it. Of course, I will be happy to remove this post if the original will be found. It's all [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799) plus a rescaling according to the number of pixels. I add an arrow that points to the coordinate at `(300,200)` in pixel units. (I named [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YijY.jpg) `Einstein.jpg`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics{Einstein.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(${(1/782)}*(image.south east)$)},
    y={(${(1/512)}*(image.north west)$)}]
    \coordinate (X) at (300,200);
    \draw[blue,latex-,blue,line width=2pt] (X) -- ++(2cm,1cm);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to draw an actual grid, use.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics{Einstein.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(${(1/782)}*(image.south east)$)},
    y={(${(1/512)}*(image.north west)$)}]
    \draw (0,0) grid[step=1] (782,512);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```